# Oracle Golden Gate or SQL Server Replication

Tags: sql-server, oracle, database-replication, oracle-golden-gate

I have detailed a scenario below in which we need to access our data in a vendors private cloud. I know sql server replication but am not very familiar with GoldenGate outside of the basic concept.

- Can Golden gate work across the web, from one private cloud to another cloud subscription?
- Is there any benefit of golden gate over sql server or vice versa?

Scenario:
We use a vendors online application. The vendor application is hosted in their own cloud along with all of our data.

We need direct access to our data for warehousing and pumping into downstream systems.

The vendor does not provide direct access to the production database for good reason, but they also do not provide any means for us to access the data.
We are proposing a reporting snapshot/replica of the production database.

We use sql server in azure, vendor uses oracle in their own private cloud.

Comment: Source database is SQL Server or Oracle? Target is SQL Server or Oracle?

Comment: And please write what do you mean by saying "SQL Server Replication". What exactly do you want to use?

Comment: thats all detailed. post mentions i am extracting from vendor, vendor uses oracle, and that we are using sql server. when i say sql server replication, i mean just that, sql server replication (hope that doesnt sound rude). i know that sql server replication can have an oracle publisher so its currently a potential option, but im unsure if its a better option than oracle golden gate.

Comment: You have mentioned that you have to replicate from a Vendor (Oracle) to MS SQL. Is that correct? What kind of replication does MS SQL provide for that you want to use?

Comment: sql server replication allows using oracle as a publisher (source).
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/oracle-publisher?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: "The vendor does not provide direct access to the production database for good reason, but they also do not provide any means for us to access the data. We are proposing a reporting snapshot/replica of the production database." "vendor uses oracle in their own private cloud."  - so this means you replicate from Vendor - that is Oracle ... ??? How does work SQL Server Replication from Oracle?

Comment: the proposal is they give us a login with requisite permissions that the SQL Server publisher will use to access the oracle database. Its just one proposal, goldengate is the other. were trying to identify the best solution for us. the previous link describes the process. Not to be rude, but the original question was which approach would be better. if you're not anyway familiar with sql server replication, its likely you wont be able to give a comparative analysis. perhaps i will phrase my question better next time.

Comment: But this is ancient history. The link  you have provided says that "Only support Oracle 10g or earlier". Are you replicating from so old database? Have you verified the technical requirements? Microsoft discourages to use this technology and tells to use SSIS instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft SQL Replication is [supported only for Oracle up to 10g](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/oracle-publisher?view=sql-server-2017). So the question is actually: either to use Oracle GoldenGate or downgrade the Oracle database to unsupported version 10g and use unsupported Microsoft SQL Server Publisher.

You might actually ask: to use **Oracle GoldenGate** or maybe some other software like **Dell Shareplex** or **Attunity**. Those products support Oracle as a source database and are fully supported.

Comment: Excellent point and an answer to my question. Appreciate your expertise and knowledge.